# cs50 speller - C language

Tags: arrays, c, pointers, hashtable, cs50

I am a little lost in this problem (this is the first CS course I have taken) and I would like for someone to look this code and tell me if it look ok or if I am on the right track.

The idea is to upload a dictionary and implement a hash table.

I am trying to use a hash table with 17576 boxes (26<sup>3</sup> for aaa, aab...).

Thanks

```
// Represents a node in a hash table
typedef struct node
{
    char word[LENGTH + 1];
    struct node *next;
} node;

// TODO: Choose number of buckets in hash table
// Lets use a hash table of 17.576 (26*26*26) boxes for aaa aab aac ...
const unsigned int N = 17576;

// Hash table
node *table[N];

// Loads dictionary into memory, returning true if successful, else false
bool load(const char *dictionary)
{
    // TODO
    FILE *file = fopen(dictionary, "r");

    if (file == NULL)
    {
        printf("Could not open file\n");
        return false;
    }

    string word_from_dictionary[1];
    int count_words_uploaded = 0;

    //Initializing the values of the hash table to NULL

    for (int i = 0; i < N; i++)
    {
        table[i] = NULL;
    }

    while (fscanf(file, "%s", word_from_dictionary[0]) != EOF)
    {
        count_words_uploaded++;
        int index = hash(word_from_dictionary[0]);
        // Now I have the index where it belongs into the hash table.

        node *n = malloc(sizeof(node));
        strcpy(n->word, word_from_dictionary[0]);
        n->next = NULL;

        // Now I need to link this to the hash table or to the linked list linked to the hash table

        // first option: the hash table is void so I can put this there.
        if (table[index]->next == NULL)
        {
            table[index]->next = n;
        }
        // The other option is that the first place in the hash table is being used so I have to iterate over
        // the link list to get mine in there.
        // We are looking for better time management so I will try to use the endpend prepend version
        else
        {
            // I want an auxiliary ptr so that I can prepend n - I need to keep ptr pointing to t=0 while I prepend what i want
            node *ptr = table[index]->next;
            // I want our main pointer (table->next) to point to n (the current word) and I want ptr (auxiliary) to keep pointing to
            // our linked list so there is no leak of memory. So now I want to make the prepend.

            table[index]->next = n;
            n->next = ptr;
            // Now current word is pointing to our old linked list so there is no leak of memory.
        }
    }
    fclose(file);
    return true;
}
```

My idea was to open the file and read it, store that string into a array of size 1. that will be my current word.

Then I would like to assign it a value (aaa = 0; but that is another function).

I would like to create a node and copy the word into its box.

Now I want to put it into the table[index]

if the box is NULL then I just plug my pointer in there.

if the box is being used I would like to prepend that word so my idea is:
I want a *ptr (an auxiliary pointer) that will point to my linked list - then I want my hash table to point to my current pointer "n" (that has the current word) - And now I want n to point to ptr because it will have the address of the linked list.

Comment: This question is too vague. Please ask a specific question, not a general "does my code look good?". If you think the code works, you can ask for advice on improving it at [codereview.se]. If it doesn't work, explain the problem you're having.

Comment: Yeah - please note that writing code is the easy part.  Testing, debugging and verification is the hard part and, if you cannot do that, you cannot program computers.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are some problems in the code:

- `string word_from_dictionary[1];` does not create a proper destination for `fscanf()`. You should define a `char` array:

  ```
    char word_from_dictionary[100];
  ```

  and use `fscanf()` his way to read the next word from the dictionary:

  ```
    while (fscanf(file, "%99s", word_from_dictionary) == 1)
  ```
- in order to insert the node into the hash table, you should not test `if (table[index]->next == NULL)` because `table[index]` may be null.  You should instead simply write:

  ```
    n->next = table[index];
    table[index] = n;
  ```

  because it does not matter in which order the words appear in the buckets.
- there is no good reason to make the hash table size `N` 26<sup>3</sup>.  I'm afraid you are going to use the first 3 letters of the word as a hash key.  This is inefficient as there will be many empty slots and many collisions in the hash table. You should implement the `hash` function as some kind of shifted sum of all the letters modulo the array size `N`, preferably a prime number using unsigned arithmetics (`unsigned int` or `size_t` type).
- Note also that `const unsigned int N = 17576;` defines a variable in C and you cannot define the Hash table as `node *table[N]` at the global scope because `N` is not a constant expression.  This may seem silly, but you should use `#define N 17576` or `enum { N = 17576 };` to make `N` a constant expression.

Answer (score 0):

It looks like you want to replace all of these:

```
table[index]->next
```

with

```
table[index]
```

table is an array of pointers to a node.